How I can cout vector
On python I do that
x = [1,2,3,4]
print(x)

How I can convert it to c++
I try this way but it give me error

std::vector<int> x = {1,2,3,4};

cout << x;


Error content


invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__ndk1::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'std::vector<int>')

        std::cout << x;

Also I won't do it with that way
std::vector<int> x = {1,2,3,4};
for (int i: x){
    std::cout << i;
}


Vectors/Containers are not printable by themselves, you have to print them yourself.

write an overload for ostream operator<<,  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<int>&).

BTW: I searched for "[c++] print vector" and that was the first result. Please, if you are stuck, do some research first.

"Also I won't do it with that way" ?!? Why?

You can write a print function with the two-line for-loop, and then you can do print(x) just like in python. And if your compiler happens to support C++23, you can even use std::print instead.

How I can convert it to c++ -- In general, do not use python or any other computer language as a model in learning C++.  If you continue to do this, you will end up with 1) Buggy programs,  2) Inefficient programs, 3) Programs that look weird to a C++ programmer, and 4) Totally miss the simple C++ ways of doing things because those things have no equivalent in the language you are trying to copy.

It's fairly simple using std::copy or just loop over the vector and print each element in turn.

Use the following
for (auto &e : x)
{
   std::cout << e << std::endl;
}

should do the trick
It just goes through the list
